# Python, pass jsonb as parameter to postgres function?

Tags: python, postgresql, function, psycopg2

There is a function advanced.func_insert with a single parameter of type jsonb

I'm trying to pass the following:

```
data = [[1, 'textData111'], [2, 'textData222'], [3, 'textData333']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text_data'])
j = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))
j = json.dumps(j)

cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
cursor.callproc('advanced.func_insert', [j,])
```

It just prints the j, not doing anything for some reason, what is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to put following lines in the end:

```
cursor.close()
connection.commit()
```

The function is supposed to insert rows to existing table and return void